# Programmatic Email Image Randomly Resizes (aspx/vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, email

I am sending out emails to my Outlook inbox Programmatically via VB.net.

A part of my email is being added through a div in my aspx, as you can see in the div's code I have pasted, there's an image I am attaching on the right hand cell of the div, it seems when I open the email, the image randomly changes between to sizes when I re open the email.

I tried attaching my image direct from vb but I encounter the same problem.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions or advice for my problem.

Here is my aspx for the div:

```
    <div id="div2" runat="server" class="div1">
                    <table id="TABLE3" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Verdana" width="100%" class="auto-style14">
                        <tr>                              
                            <td style="font-size: 10pt; text-align: right" class="auto-style16">
                                <asp:Image ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/Logo.bmp" ImageAlign="Right" Height="40%" Width="40%" />
                                <br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Here is my vb that attaches the div to the email:

```
   Dim sb2 As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
            Dim sw2 As StringWriter = New StringWriter(sb2)
            Dim htw2 As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw2)
            div2.RenderControl(htw2)
```

.

```
     .Body += sb2.ToString() + "<br />"
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to add controls to a html string that is going to an unknown location then it is best not to add Dynamic values for the height and width.

You should set the height and with to a static value i.e. 50px

Comment: Seems that even when I set the height/width in pixels, the problem is still there.